# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre los terminos Falacia y Paralogismo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, definiciones, sinónimos

Cabe resaltar que tanto el término *falacia* al igual que el término *paralogismo* se encuentran haciendo referencia a un razonamiento inválido

> [falacia](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HVXQdUl)
>
> 1. f. Engaño, fraude o mentira con que se intenta dañar a alguien.
>
> [paralogismo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RrH0kiu)
>
> 1. m. Razonamiento falso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pues sin ser experto en filosofía, me gustaría destacar una importante diferencia que ya aparece en la definición del DRAE de ambos términos (que @Diego ha incluido en tu pregunta)

> [paralogismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RrH0kiu)
>   1. m. Razonamiento falso.
>
> [falacia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HVXQdUl)
>   1. f. **Engaño**, fraude o mentira con que se intenta **dañar** a alguien.
>   2. f. Hábito de emplear falsedades en **daño** ajeno.

Dicha diferencia también se aprecia en la definición de ambos términos en la Wikipedia

> [paralogismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paralogismo) 
> Un paralogismo es un argumento o razonamiento
>   inválido, que se plantea **sin una voluntad de engaño**
>
> [falacia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falacia)
>   En lógica, una falacia (del latín: fallacia, ‘**engaño**’) es un argumento
>   que parece válido, pero no lo es. Algunas falacias se cometen
>   intencionalmente **para persuadir o manipular a los demás**

Parece que ambas fuentes coinciden en que la principal diferencia estriba en la intencionalidad de causar perjuicio o daño que conlleva la falacia y que está ausente del paralogismo.

Esto no quiere decir que toda falacia implique engaño. Ambas palabras pueden emplearse para denominar el mismo concepto pero mientras que paralogismo es neutra, falacia tiene matices negativos. Además falacia es mucho más amplia pues es sinónimo de engaño y mentira, cosa que no cumple paralogismo.

Por último, si nos limitamos al marco de los razonamientos o argumentaciones, creo que el uso de falacia está mucho más extendido.